# Iniciar grails application

Tags: javascript, html, groovy, grails, atom

Então, estou começando a usar o grails/groovy agora, junto com html/css/javascript e, como um bom novato, estou cheio de dúvidas.

Criei uma página html de login com google plus e queria rodar a aplicação grails pra ver o que está acontecendo mas até agora não consegui roda-la de maneira alguma, não sei como iniciar a aplicação. Antes que perguntem, o grails já está setado nas variáveis de ambiente do windows.

Obrigado desde já pelas respostas e dicas :).

Comment: Olá Erick, é dificil saber o que já fizeste e o que possa ser o problema. Podes descrever melhor os passos que já deste e onde estás parado agora?

Comment: Então @Sergio, eu sou bem novato, então perdoe se eu falar besteira. Eu criei o projeto grails e to usando o atom como IDE, até agora tudo que eu fiz foi criar um page html com o login, como eu disse aí em cima e eu queria iniciar a aplicação grails para criar um localhost e ver como a page ta se comportando, mas não sei como. Tu poderia me dizer passo a passo como se faz?

Comment: Olá, qual a versão que você está usando do grails?

Answer (score 1):

Basta você entrar na raiz do projeto e executar o comando `grails run-app`.

Se você precisar de mais ajuda na questão da visualização dos recursos estaticos só falar.

Answer (score 1):

Erick, é importante você dizer qual versão do Grails você está usando, e como estão configuradas suas variáveis de ambiente, principalmente a GRAILS_HOME e a JAVA_HOME.

Tente no terminal você digitar **grails --version** dentro do diretório onde está a aplicação que você criou. Esse comando deve mostrar qual versão do Grails está instalada no seu pc. Além disso, tente rodar no mesmo diretório **grails run-app**. Caso apareça algum erro, poste ele aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Bom primeiramente voce precisa de algumas variaveis instaladas

Primeiro o Java Home
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/

Depois o Grails Home
http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/gettingStarted.html

E lembre-se de inserir ambos no Path de seu computador.

Depois disso basta rodar o comando

```
grails run-app
```

Ou

```
grails
```

E depois

```
run-app
```

Answer (score -1):

de um `grails clean` e depois rode um `grails run-app`